# Different results GPU & CPU when more than one 8 work items per group

Tags: opencl

I'm new in open cl. And tried as my first work to write code that checks intersection between many polylines to single polygon.

I'm running the code in both cpu and gpu.. and get different results.

First I sent `NULL` as `local` parameter when called `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kIntersect, 1, NULL, &global, null, 2, &evtCalcBounds, &evtKernel);
```

After trying many things i saw that if i send 1 as local it is working good. and returning the same results for the cpu and gpu.

```
size_t local = 1;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kIntersect, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 2, &evtCalcBounds, &evtKernel);
```

Played abit more and found that the cpu returns false result when i run the kernel with local 8 or more (for some reason).

I'm not using any local memory, just globals and privates.

I didn't added the code because i think it is irrelevant to the problem (note that for single work group it is working good), and it is long. If it is needed, i will try to simplify it.

The code flow is going like this:

I have polylines coordinates stored in a big buffer. and the single polygon in another. In addition i'm providing another buffer with single int that holds the current results count. All buffers are `__global` arguments.

In the kernel i'm simply checking intersection between all the lines of the "`polyline[get_global(0)]`" with the lines of the `polygon`. If true,
i'm using `atomic_inc` for the results count. There is no read and write memory from the same buffer, no barriers or mem fences,... the `atomic_inc` is the only thread safe mechanism i'm using.

**-- UPDATE --**

Added my code:

I know that i can maybe have better use of open cl functions for calculating some vectors, but for now, i'm simply convert code from my old regular CPU single threaded program to CL. so this is not my concern now.

```
bool isPointInPolygon(float x, float y, __global float* polygon) {
    bool blnInside = false;
    uint length = convert_uint(polygon[4]);
    int s = 5;
    uint j = length - 1;
    for (uint i = 0; i < length; j = i++) {
        uint realIdx = s + i * 2;
        uint realInvIdx = s + j * 2;
        if (((polygon[realIdx + 1] > y) != (polygon[realInvIdx + 1] > y)) &&
            (x < (polygon[realInvIdx] - polygon[realIdx]) * (y - polygon[realIdx + 1]) / (polygon[realInvIdx + 1] - polygon[realIdx + 1]) + polygon[realIdx]))
            blnInside = !blnInside;
    }
    return blnInside;
}

bool isRectanglesIntersected(float p_dblMinX1, float p_dblMinY1,
    float p_dblMaxX1, float p_dblMaxY1,
    float p_dblMinX2, float p_dblMinY2,
    float p_dblMaxX2, float p_dblMaxY2) {
    bool blnResult = true;

    if (p_dblMinX1 > p_dblMaxX2 ||
        p_dblMaxX1 < p_dblMinX2 ||
        p_dblMinY1 > p_dblMaxY2 ||
        p_dblMaxY1 < p_dblMinY2) {
        blnResult = false;
    }

    return blnResult;
}

bool isLinesIntersects(
    double Ax, double Ay,
    double Bx, double By,
    double Cx, double Cy,
    double Dx, double Dy) {

    double  distAB, theCos, theSin, newX, ABpos;

    //  Fail if either line is undefined.
    if (Ax == Bx && Ay == By || Cx == Dx && Cy == Dy) 
        return false;

    //  (1) Translate the system so that point A is on the origin.
    Bx -= Ax; By -= Ay;
    Cx -= Ax; Cy -= Ay;
    Dx -= Ax; Dy -= Ay;

    //  Discover the length of segment A-B.
    distAB = sqrt(Bx*Bx + By*By);

    //  (2) Rotate the system so that point B is on the positive X axis.
    theCos = Bx / distAB;
    theSin = By / distAB;
    newX = Cx*theCos + Cy*theSin;
    Cy = Cy*theCos - Cx*theSin; Cx = newX;
    newX = Dx*theCos + Dy*theSin;
    Dy = Dy*theCos - Dx*theSin; Dx = newX;

    //  Fail if the lines are parallel.
    return (Cy != Dy);
}

bool isPolygonInersectsPolyline(__global float* polygon, __global float* polylines, uint startIdx) {

    uint polylineLength = convert_uint(polylines[startIdx]);
    uint start = startIdx + 1;

    float x1 = polylines[start];
    float y1 = polylines[start + 1];
    float x2;
    float y2;

    int polygonLength = convert_uint(polygon[4]);
    int polygonLength2 = polygonLength * 2;
    int startPolygonIdx = 5;

    for (int currPolyineIdx = 0; currPolyineIdx < polylineLength - 1; currPolyineIdx++)
    {
        x2 = polylines[start + (currPolyineIdx*2) + 2];
        y2 = polylines[start + (currPolyineIdx*2) + 3];

        float polyX1 = polygon[0];
        float polyY1 = polygon[1];
        for (int currPolygonIdx = 0; currPolygonIdx < polygonLength; ++currPolygonIdx)
        {
            float polyX2 = polygon[startPolygonIdx + (currPolygonIdx * 2 + 2) % polygonLength2];
            float polyY2 = polygon[startPolygonIdx + (currPolygonIdx * 2 + 3) % polygonLength2];

            if (isLinesIntersects(x1, y1, x2, y2, polyX1, polyY1, polyX2, polyY2)) {
                return true;
            }

            polyX1 = polyX2;
            polyY1 = polyY2;
        }

        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
    }

    // No intersection found till now so we check containing
    return isPointInPolygon(x1, y1, polygon);
}

__kernel void calcIntersections(__global float* polylines, // My flat points array - [pntCount, x,y,x,y,...., pntCount, x,y,... ]
                    __global float* pBounds, // The rectangle bounds of each polyline - set of 4 values [top, left, bottom, right....]
                    __global uint* pStarts, // The start index of each polyline in the polylines array
                    __global float* polygon, // The polygon i want to intersect with - first 4 items are the rectangle bounds [top, left, bottom, right, pntCount, x,y,x,y,x,y....]
                    __global float* output, // Result array for saving the intersections polylines indices
                    __global uint* resCount) // The result count
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    uint start = convert_uint(pStarts[i]);

    if (isRectanglesIntersected(pBounds[i * 4], pBounds[i * 4 + 1], pBounds[i * 4 + 2], pBounds[i * 4 + 3],
        polygon[0], polygon[1], polygon[2], polygon[3])) {

        if (isPolygonInersectsPolyline(polygon, polylines, start)){
            int oldVal = atomic_inc(resCount);
            output[oldVal] = i;
        }
    }   
}
```

Can anyone explain it to me ?

Comment: Can you post some of the kernel code? It looks like your kernel depends on local size, so you are reusing some data that you shouldn't between workitems.

Comment: Another thing, is that if refuses to work with some specific local size, it is because it does not meet the device limits, or global size is not divisible by local size.

Comment: This is what i thought so, but since i'm not using any local memory, it should not happened. isn't it ? Regarding the device limits and divisible. The limit is 1024 and i used only divisible values (anyway, it returns error when using those invalid values in the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` call). so this is not the case. Anyway, i will add my code to my post.

Comment: I have been analizing the code, and should work for any local size. Can you check all the errors? Maybe the kernel is failing in some out-of-bounds memory call...

Comment: No errors at all.. not at any stage of my flow. I've digged down and saw that the results are different after calling the `isPointInPolygon` method inside the `isPolygonInersectsPolyline`.. When i just return `true` there it is working. But still this function is very simple and worked well when i tried it separately. Is it Ok to break out from loops and function with `return` or `break`?

Comment: Even more, when i'm running `isPolygonInersectsPolyline` main loop and then after the calling `isPointInPolygon` the problems occures. if i'm skipping the main loop, it is ok.. somehow it is connected to the amount of code or something like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94311/discussion-between-raziza-o-and-darkzeros).

Comment: Did you check the return value (error code) of the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel? It may because the kernel is not successfully launched.

Comment: No single error all along the flow. From creating context, buffers, arguments,... To enqueue .. Not a single error